# Can I use Meteor js to make a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, google-chrome-app

Hello I'm considering using meteor to make a web app, but I was wondering how easy it is to convert it to a chrome app afterwards. I've seen packmeteor on npm (but that doesn't seem to have been updated in a while).

Does anyone have some experience with converting a meteor app to a chrome app? if so, is there anything to be weary of?

In general would it be a good idea/doable or should I just use a different framework?

Edit: Some basic capabilities about the app would be: MongoDB or CouchDB, Twilio integration, and handling documents and notes.

Comment: Could you add some more details about what kind of capabilities the app will have?

Comment: Hello @bruno, do you have answer for this question ?

Comment: I don't think so, we ended up using something else.